# Does QMovie support an alpha channel?

Tags: c++, qt

I swapped out `QImageReader` for `QMovie` to easily loop an animated GIF. However, the `QImage` returned by `QMovie::currentImage()` does not have an alpha channel. If I use `QImageReader::read()`, it does have an alpha channel. The documentation does not mention any difference between the two regarding alpha. Is there any way to preserve the alpha channel when using QMovie?

```
QMovie movie( "ExampleAnimation.gif" );
movie.jumpToFrame( 0 );
const auto movieFrame = movie.currentImage();
DEBUG_LOG() << movieFrame.hasAlphaChannel(); // false

QImageReader reader( "ExampleAnimation.gif" );
reader.jumpToImage( 0 );
const auto readerImage = reader.read();
DEBUG_LOG() << readerImage.hasAlphaChannel(); // true
```

Comment: I don't reproduce the problem, have you used QMovie's start method?

Comment: @eyllanesc I did not call `start()` originally, but adding it made no difference. The image still has format `Format_RGB32`.

Comment: Then please provide a [mre]. Maybe your implementation is not correct, I just tested and I do not see what you indicate

Comment: @eyllanesc Edited with example that I just tested. Not sure what the difference could be...

Comment: In my case they both return True. I am on Linux with Qt 5.15.2, what is your environment? Could you share the .gif?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue and I would like to provide an answer in case others are in a similar situation.

The GIF file I was using had an alpha channel, but it didn't have any transparent pixels. Internally, `QMovie` calls `QPixmap::fromImage()`, which seems to remove the alpha channel if it is not used.